# Manually install GRUB

Tags: grub2

I have the latest Puppy Linux (5.20, I think) but it has a problem with grub install at the end of the setup process.

How can I install grub (or grub2, the easiest one will be great) manually using my Ubuntu 10.04 CD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Boot from CD.
2. Run `fdisk -l` and see which is your linux partition, say `/dev/sda2`.
3. Mount the partition to say `/mnt` using `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
4. Now run the following magic command from anywhere:

   ```
   grub-install --root-partition=/mnt /dev/sda
   ```

   You will get the message

   > no error reported
5. Reboot.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer a GUI way then download [Grub Customizer Portable](http://portablelinuxapps.org/show/?d=Grub%20Customizer%202.1.DirIcon) then mark the applications ‘executable’ after download - Right click > Properties > Permissions > Check ‘allow executing as a programme’  then double-click and run and then click File -> install to MBR.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please see link:

[GRUB Manual - Install](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_3.html)

Keep me informed