# Problem with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, boot, windows-7

First of all this is the proceed that I followed to install it:

1. I deleted system partition (that uses 100Mb and store the boot files) from my HD and I write the boot on my `C:` where Windows is installed.
2. Then I inserted the CD with Ubuntu and I loaded it, then I selected the option that allows you to install with Windows 7, I resized `C:` partition, and the installation started.
3. After all the installation finished, Ubuntu ran well, then I restarted, grub loaded, and I selected Windows 7 Loader or something like that, Windows started to load, it shows the progress bar, and then bam! A BSoD appeared, I restarted and I tried to load Windows again, BSoD again, but another problem appeared, my PC restarts again, but grub doesn't load anymore and my PC starts to reboot and reboot, so I had to force it tu turn off.
4. Then I had to repair MBR with Windows DVD, and magically Windows 7 loaded.

My question is, how can I fix this because I really want to use Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Don't think that a 100MB partition exist to fill space, it contains the boot files for windows.

Answer (score 3):

The System Reserved partition is necessary for windows to boot. The BSOD occured because you deleted the partition ;P

When you ran the windows repair disc, the GRUB bootloader was overwritten. Assuming the System Reserved partition has been restored you should be able to set GRUB back up by following these steps:

*steps taken from raheals solution to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25425/manually-install-grub) question.*

1.boot from Ubuntu live cd (same one you used to install ubuntu with). Select "Try Ubuntu".

2.In a terminal (Accessories > Terminal) run `fdisk -l` and see which is your linux partition say `/dev/sda2`

3.mount the partition to say `/mnt` using `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

4.now the magic command run the following from anywhere

5.`grub-install --root-partition=/mnt /dev/sda` you will get the message "no error reported"

6.reboot

7.enjoy!

Comment: 1.boot from CD, possibly means boot from Ubuntu CD.