# cannot get back to windows after getting my windows7 to work

Tags: dual-boot

I installed ubuntu to get access to a windows 7 install that was not working. I got it fixed, but now I cannot get back to ubuntu. I always starts in windows.

Answer (score 1):

`GRUB` is the program that loads Ubuntu (or a menu letting you select which OS to load). To install it, look at the answer to this question:

[Installing Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25425/manually-install-grub)

There are things can go wrong with that answer, so feel free to comment on this answer and I will try to work with you. First thing to post would be the output of the command `fdisk -l` and the command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` (which you type at a command line shell -- press CTRL+SHIFT+T). You can edit your question with this information and use four spaces to indent shell output

```
like this
```

Welcome to Ubuntu, I hope you like it here.