# To windows 7 from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

So I just installed Ubuntu on my families desktop, everybody loves it except my brother. When I restart my computer it doesn't give me the option to pick Ubuntu or Windows 7. So I'm lost (I have all my windows 7 stuff on my drives so I definitely ran them side by side) so how do I switch back to Windows?

Comment: I also don't have a windows 7 disk. will I need one to be able to do this?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) URL. This will give use valuable information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have windows and ubuntu installed on the same pc?

If so you need to install GRUB or another Bootloader.

From user [hhlp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25425/manually-install-grub)

1.boot from cd

2.run fdisk -l and see which is your linux partition say /dev/sda2

3.mount the partition to say /mnt using mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

4.now the magic command run the following from anywhere

5.grub-install --root-partition=/mnt /dev/sda you will get the message "no error reported"

6.reboot

7.enjoy!

Comment: I do have GRUB but noooooo idea how to use it

Comment: If GRUB is installed it show provide you with a menu, where you can choose Windows or Ubuntu. Do you have such options? What does Grub shows you?

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu, try opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
Then enter:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then paste the results back here or make sure that there is an NTFS or FAT32 partition in the output. If NTFS or FAT32 does show up, you can enter the following in another or the same terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober ntfs-3g
sudo update-grub
```

This should say:

> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinux-3....
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img...
>   ...
>   Found Windows 7...

If it does find Windows, run the next command (if it doesn't find Windows, there may be some additional steps/installs to run.)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Where /dev/sdX is the primary bootable drive you want to install Grub to. (usually /dev/sda in a computer with a single hard drive.) If everything went well, you should be able to select Windows next time you reboot. 
For more information about Grub, you can check out
[Ubuntu's help page on Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)