# Will formatting a USB drive remove the Ubuntu Bootloader installed in it?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, bootloader

I have a PC, where I installed Ubuntu on the hard disk, and the bootloader on the USB drive. Please don't ask me why :P  . I Want to know the answer if the formatting is done normally, using the right click popup menu and clicking on the format button, either on Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: Do you want to remove the Ubuntu bootloader, or do you want to keep it in the USB drive? - I would suggest that you install the bootloader into the internal drive. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Formatting will not **typically** remove the MBR. The MBR and the partition table both live in the first 512 bytes of the drive. Wiping the first 512 bytes of the drive will eliminate both which is not what you have in mind. To eliminate only the content of the MBR (Master Boot Record) issue the command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1 where **/dev/sdX** is the drive you wish to wipe the boot record from.

**Be careful** to confirm that you have the right device beforehand by checking the output of `sudo fdisk -l` or `lsblk` or `lsscsi`

Ideally, in your situation I think what you wish to do is to [install grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25425/manually-install-grub) to the MBR of the Hard Disk

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/

Comment: So, right clicking on the drive and formatting won't remove the bootloader in any OS, right?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Formatting is a high level process typically done on a partition and not on an entire device.  I try to never say never because all things are possible given the right (or wrong) conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**mkusb** provides a surefire method to restore a working USB drive to it's original condition.

The Wipe menu gives options to zero out the first megabyte of the drive, (wiping out the MBR), restore the MSDOS partition table and then partition the drive with a FAT32 file system.

The script uses dd to do this, but it wraps a layer of safety around the process using a simple GUI with checks and double checks.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe